# webservice using source code under apache 2.0 license

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, apache-2.0, website

Question is: I have developed a software which extends an open source project licensed under the Apache 2.0 license. The original open source project has been bought from another company which gave me the possibility to modify, extend, and sell the code. Now I wanna build a cloud service based on this software allowing users to use it thru a web application.

Do I have any limitation with the license?

Am I forced to give away the source code of the project?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have any limitation with the license?

No.

> Am I forced to give away the source code of the project?

No.

Mere internal usage (including as a backend webservice) of Apache-2.0-licensed code does not have specific obligations.

I still would document my changes in the source and keep intact all the notices though if I ever redistribute code in the future.